# Can't install gems using asdf

Tags: ruby, asdf-vm

So I'm switching to a project that is using `ruby`. They use `asdf` as a package manager

I’m having trouble installing the gems, I’m using `zsh` and I’m thinking there might be an issue with the paths

Running `gem install bundler` outputs: `You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.`

`ruby -v`
outputs: `ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]`

`which ruby`
output: `/usr/bin/ruby`

And I tried setting a global version for ruby with `asdf global ruby 2.5.3` but that doesn’t seem to change the version

This is my `gem environment`:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.5.2.3
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.3.7 (2018-03-28 patchlevel 456) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
  - USER INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /Users/carlos.grijalva/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /Library/Ruby/Site
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - universal-darwin-18
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
     - /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.3/usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/shims
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/.asdf/bin
     - /Users/carlos.grijalva/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/bin
     - /bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /sbin
```

Comment: Seems like an asdf installation/etc issue. Did you add the asdf lines to your shell startup?

Comment: Hmm, should that be done in the `.zshrc` file? Not sure where to add the lines

Comment: Yes, since that's your startup file. When you install asdf it actually says what to do. I'm not saying it's the (or only) issue, but... you do actually need to give asdf access to your shims/etc.

Comment: Hmm, trying to figure out what exact lines to add for this...

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you may need to add the relevant lines to your `.zshrc` so asdf shims get recognized. You can find the instructions [here](https://asdf-vm.com/#/core-manage-asdf-vm?id=install-asdf-vm)

For macOS & zsh the correct lines to append to .zshrc are:

```
echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/asdf.sh' >> ~/.zshrc
echo -e '\n. $HOME/.asdf/completions/asdf.bash' >> ~/.zshrc
```

After doing so, either `source ~/.zshrc` or restart your terminal

Comment: Saw that too and ran those exact commands. For some reason I'm still getting:

`You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0 directory.`

And I can't seem to change the version of ruby with `asdf`. Not sure what else could be happening

Comment: @CarlosG90 Did you open a new terminal so they're actually in effect? All those commands do is modify your startup script.

Comment: Yeah, modified and ran `source ~/.zshrc` also checked the actual file is changed and restarted the terminal multiple times. Ruby version doesn't seem to change.

Comment: @CarlosG90 can you run `which ruby`, `which asdf`, `which gem` and post the results? Also, inspect your $PATH and see where `/Users/username/asdf` folders are in relation to `/usr/bin` (`/usr/bin` is where the system ruby/gem commands are kept)

Comment: it seems that the paths were incorrect, I was able to add them and the shims are there now! Thanks!